# Twitter API simplexml_load_string stop working

Tags: php, xml, api, twitter, simplexml

This morning my PHP script, for Twitter OAuth posting, stopped working. I suspect that Twitter added some rows for the returned string. Can anyone help how to debug this.

Thanks

```
Warning:  simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 74: 
parser error : Entity 'copy' not defined in /nfs/c05/h01/mnt/82363/domains/html/c/cron.m.php on line 429

Warning:  simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:           
<li class="first">&copy; 2011 Twitter</li> in /nfs/c05/h01/mnt/82363/domains/html/c/cron.m.php on line 429

Warning:  simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in /nfs/c05/h01/mnt/82363/domains/html/c/cron.m.php on line 429
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML contains HTML entities. `&copy;` is not valid in XML. As a workaround you could pre-filter the document before handing it over to SimpleXML:

```
$xml = file_get_contents(...);
$xml = strtr($xml, array_flip(array_diff(
           get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES),
           get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS)
       )));

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for UTF-8 string xml data.

$xml = mb_strtr($xml, array_flip(array_diff(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES),get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS))));

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

Answer (score 0):

echo the string and look for the new changes that were made to the xml file,

It's possible that they added a namespace.

Comment: also show the code where you load the string, maybe you require something different

Comment: look for `'copy'` in the xml;